# SQL CASE conditions always returning ELSE value

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I have a mini database (`mymoney`) which has a column called `total_amount`. Now I would like to get this column and ad an extra column `GRP2` (with values `low`, `medium` or `high`) based on the row value in the `total_amount` column. **So I have this**:

```
total_amount
5000
27000
36000
50000
```

**And I would like to the this**:

```
total_amount    GRP2
5000            low
27000           low
36000           medium
50000           high
```

I tried with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT mymoney.total_amount,
    CASE mymoney.total_amount
        WHEN mymoney.total_amount <= 30000 THEN 'low'
        WHEN mymoney.total_amount >= 31000 AND mymoney.total_amount <= 40000 THEN 'medium'
        ELSE 'high'
    END AS GRP2
FROM mymoney
```

But in `GRP2` I get `high` everywhere, even though there are clearly numbers in `total_amount` which should be marked `low` and `medium`. (btw: the data types for the values in `total_amount` are all integers).

```
total_amount    GRP2
5000            high
27000           high
36000           high
50000           high
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `CASE` expression. Try like this:

```
SELECT total_amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN total_amount <= 30000 THEN 'low'
        WHEN total_amount > 30000 AND total_amount <= 40000 THEN 'medium'
        ELSE 'high'
    END AS GRP2
FROM gates_money
```

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much, this worked! :) (I also saw a typo in my question: `gates_money` should be `mymoney`, will edit now)

Answer (score 1):

You are use simple CASE expression whereas you need searched CASE expression

```
SELECT mymoney.total_amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN mymoney.total_amount <= 30000 THEN 'low'
        WHEN mymoney.total_amount >= 31000 AND mymoney.total_amount <= 40000 THEN 'medium'
        ELSE 'high'
    END AS GRP2
FROM mymoney
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
SELECT mymoney.total_amount, 
GRP2 = CASE 
        WHEN mymoney.total_amount <= 30000 THEN 'low'
        WHEN mymoney.total_amount >= 31000 AND mymoney.total_amount <= 40000  THEN 'medium'
        ELSE 'high'
       END 
FROM gates_money
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Regards,

Comment: you link doesn't work and the question was about SQLite, _not_ about SQL Server

Comment: My bad, thank you! I'll pay more attention in the future.